# Can we just go ahead and start a topic of the week?

Tags: discussion

I know doing a topic of the week has been discussed before. What I'm suggesting is that even with out a reward we just start a topic of the week to generate more questions on this site during Beta. I also think that a general topic will generate more questions. Such as Classic TV Sitcoms would generate more questions then Sanford & Son. So should we go ahead and start a topic of the week?

Comment: I upvoted this, but just wanted to toss out a concern. If we create a topic of the week, will that encourage more frivolous questions from users trying to meet the theme?

Comment: @Nobby At the same time, anything we do that might be promotional, whether it be topic of the week, contests, etc are bound to have people just wanting to write w/e to participate.  That's what the quality control is for.  If we see them result into utter chaos, then a re-evaluation of the idea will have to be done, or just tossed out the window completely.

Comment: Point taken. I've no idea why I'm so twitchy today.

Comment: @Nobby better to be twitchy today rather than regretful tomorrow :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that as long as we can build a list of topics that is long enough that we can be confident that the idea will not just die off, then I think that would be a good idea.

If this question gets enough support, then we could open another community-wiki question to collate and order the list of topics.

I think that people should upvote / downvote your question to register support or not. (also if people have points to make, other answers would also be welcome).